# How can I connect all nodes with lines by using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm working on the figure below, trying to connect all the vertices with multiple lines
[image]

Is it possible to number the vertices from 1 to 60 and connect them all together?

My attempts

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{place}=[circle, draw=blue,fill=yellow!20, minimum size = 8mm]
        
        % Input
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \draw node at (0, -\x*1.25) [place] (first_\x) {$\x$};
            
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \draw node at (3, -\x*1.25) [place] (first_\x) {$\x$};
            \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \node at (0, -\x*1.25) [place] (second_\x){$\x$};
    
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
            \foreach \j in {1,...,10}
                \draw [->] (first_\i) to (second_\j); 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

But I am looking for a generalization to connect the sixty vertices together. Please help

My attempts
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,longbibliography]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{place}=[circle, draw=black,fill=yellow!20, minimum size = 8mm]
 
        % A1
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \draw node at (0, -\x*1.25) [place] (A1_\x) {${\x}$};   
        
        % A2
        \foreach \x in {11,...,20}
            \node at (3, -\x*1.25) [place] (A2_\x){$\x$};
        
   
        
        % Output
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \node at (6, -\x*1.25) [place] (A3_\x){$y_\x$};
    % Input
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \draw node at (9, -\x*1.25) [place] (A4_\x) {$x_\x$};
        
        
        % Hidden 1
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \node at (12, -\x*1.25) [place] (A5_\x){$a_\x$};
        
   
        
        % Output
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \node at (15, -\x*1.25) [place] (A6_\x){$y_\x$};

            
        % A1 -> A2
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
            \foreach \j in {11,...,20}
                \draw [->] (A1_\i) to (A2_\j);
   
        %A2 -> A3
        \foreach \i in {11,...,20}
        \foreach \j in {1,...,10}
                \draw [->] (A2_\i) to (A3_\j);
                        
        % A3 -> A4
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
            \foreach \j in {1,...,10}
                \draw [->] (A3_\i) to (A4_\j);
   
        %A4 -> A5
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
        \foreach \j in {1,...,10}
                \draw [->] (A4_\i) to (A5_\j);
                        
        % A5 -> A6
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
            \foreach \j in {1,...,10}
                \draw [->] (A5_\i) to (A6_\j);
  
    \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that when the x values change, the location of the vertices changes
%A2 -> A3
\foreach \i in {11,...,20}
\foreach \j in {1,...,10}
\draw [->] (A2_\i) to (A3_\j);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need three `\foreach` commands for this. One will typeset 10 nodes below each other, one will repeat this 6 times (for each column), and one will connect a node to all nodes in the previous column (except for the nodes in the first column.

In such contexts, it makes sense to name the nodes by column number and row number for easy referencing:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle, 
        draw=blue,
        fill=yellow!20, 
        minimum size=8mm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % 6 columns
    \foreach \c in {1,...,6} {
        % 10 rows
        \foreach \r in {1,...,10} {
            \node at ({(\c-1)*3},{\r*-1.25}) [place] (n\c_\r) {$\r$};
            % connect this node to all nodes in previous column 
            % except if in first column
            \ifnum\c > 1\relax
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{\c-1}
                \foreach \p in {1,...,10} {
                    \draw (n\c_\r) -- (n\b_\p);
                }
            \fi
        }
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With this setup, it is easy to change the number of columns: Just change the relevant digit in the first `\foreach` command to something else. If you want to change the number of nodes per column, you'd need to change the relevant digits in both the other `foreach` commands, of course.

---

You might want to print the edges on the background layer so that they don't overlap the nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle, 
        draw=blue,
        fill=yellow!20, 
        minimum size=8mm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % 6 columns
    \foreach \c in {1,...,6} {
        % 10 rows
        \foreach \r in {1,...,10} {
            \node at ({(\c-1)*3},{\r*-1.25}) [place] (n\c_\r) {$\r$};
            % connect this node to all nodes in previous column 
            % except if in first column
            \ifnum\c > 1\relax
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{\c-1}
                \foreach \p in {1,...,10} {
                    \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
                        \draw (n\c_\r) -- (n\b_\p);
                    \end{scope}
                }
            \fi
        }
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With node numbers from 1 to 60:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle, 
        draw=blue,
        fill=yellow!20, 
        minimum size=8mm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % 6 columns
    \foreach \c in {1,...,6} {
        % 10 rows
        \foreach \r in {1,...,10} {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{\r+10*(\c-1)}
            \node at ({(\c-1)*3},{\r*-1.25}) [place] (n\c_\r) {$\n$};
            % connect this node to all nodes in previous column 
            % except if in first column
            \ifnum\c > 1\relax
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{\c-1}
                \foreach \p in {1,...,10} {
                    \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
                        \draw (n\c_\r) -- (n\b_\p);
                    \end{scope}
                }
            \fi
        }
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And, because I am such a fan of `\pic`s, a `\pic` implementation that allows for different numbers of vertices per layer:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newif\ifneuralnetworkcontinuousnumbering
\neuralnetworkcontinuousnumberingfalse
\newcounter{neuralnetworkvertice}

\tikzset{
    pics/neural network/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{neural network/.cd, #1}
            \setcounter{neuralnetworkvertice}{0}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\n}{dim({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/neural network/layers}})-1}
            \foreach \c in {0,...,\n} {
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\i}{array({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/neural network/layers}},\c)}
                \ifnum\c > 0\relax
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{\c-1}
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{array({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/neural network/layers}},\b)}
                \fi
                \foreach \r in {1,...,\i} {
                    \stepcounter{neuralnetworkvertice}
                    \ifneuralnetworkcontinuousnumbering
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\currvertice}{\value{neuralnetworkvertice}}
                    \else
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\currvertice}{\r}
                    \fi
                    \node[neural network/vertices] 
                        at (
                            {(\c-1)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/neural network/x distance}},
                            {(\r-\i/2)*-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/neural network/y distance}}
                        ) (-vertice \c-\r) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/neural network/vertice contents}};
                    \ifnum\c > 0\relax
                        \foreach \p in {1,...,\j} {
                            \begin{scope}[neural network/edges]
                                \draw (-vertice \b-\p) -- (-vertice \c-\r);
                            \end{scope}
                        }
                    \fi
                }
            }
        }
    },
    neural network/layers/.initial={3,5,2},
    neural network/x distance/.initial={2.5},
    neural network/y distance/.initial={1.25},
    neural network/continuous numbering/.is if={
        neuralnetworkcontinuousnumbering
    },
    neural network/vertice contents/.initial={$\currvertice$},
    neural network/vertices/.style={
        circle, 
        draw=blue,
        fill=yellow!20, 
        minimum size=8mm
    },
    neural network/edges/.style={
        on background layer
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic {neural network={layers={3,6,6,10,5}}};

\pic at (0,-10) {neural network={layers={3,6,5}, continuous numbering}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to number the nodes from 1 to 60. Is that possible?

Comment: @Emadkareem (Almost) everything is possible ... =)

Answer (score 9):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\makeatletter
\tikzgraphsset{
  grid placement/.append style={% sneak temp values out
    placement/compute position/.append code=
      \let\tikzgraphsgridrow\tikz@temp@row
      \let\tikzgraphsgridcol\tikz@temp@col}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz[@/.style={new set={col#1}}, @/.list={0, ..., 5}]
\graph[
  nodes={
    shape=circle, draw=blue, fill=yellow!20,
    set=col\tikzgraphsgridrow,
    align=center, text width=width("00"),},
  grid placement, grow down=1, branch right=2,
]{
  subgraph I_n[n=60, wrap after=10]
} [behind path] graph {
  \foreach[count=\j from 0] \i in {1, ..., 5}{
    (col\j) --[complete bipartite] (col\i)
  }
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: What an elegant answer !

Comment: Nice idea! What does `@/.style` do?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Nothing special. It just defines a style `/tikz/@` which I'm using right away. It's just an temporary throwaway name for the `.list` handler. That way you only have to change two `5`s to another number if you need another number of columns (rows for TikZ) instead of adding another `new set=col6, new set=col7, …`. Of course, the `text width` parameter should be changed at some point as well …

Comment: Oh, I see. I looked for it in the rest of the code and did not realise that it is actually used right after! Right, the `.list` handler comes in handy here.

Comment: @JasperHabicht We could use `new set/.list={col0, col..., col5}` (or just use the numbers without the prefix) but the `/tikz/@` solution seems more robust and flexible.